# How to define specific return type of react method (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript-typings

I want to define a return type of a specific react component.

For Example:

**Component 1**

```
class ComponentFoo extends React.Component<any, any> {
   public render() {…}
}
```

**Component 2**

```
class ComponentBar extends React.Component<any, any> {
    public renderComponentFoo() : ComponentFoo { <---
      return <ComponentFoo />
    }

    public render() {
      …
      {this.renderComponentFoo()}
      …
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be proper TypeScript.

Comment: Could you be more precise? what is your problem? complication error?

Comment: Does it matter in your case, why not use `any` as the return type?

Comment: I need a specific type. Quick Example: I built a table in React. And the Table head needs to be a component type of `class TableHead extends React.Component…`

Comment: TypeScript cannot differentiate instantiated JSX nodes like this. There is [an open issue to track this functionality](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699), but it would be a breaking change so it has to be carefully considered.

Answer (score 1):

Your `renderComponentFoo` method should return `React.ReactNode` instead.

JSX/TSX is just syntax sugar around `React.createElement()` which returns `React.ReactNode`. You are not returning an instance of `ComponentFoo` as your current code suggests.